# How can I cast a variable with the `object` type to class with generic type in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, clr

I have a project written in C#. I am trying to cast an object to a class that accepts enum object as a generic argument.

I have the following class

```
public class GenericEnumViewModel<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    [Required]
    public TEnum? Value { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of one of my enum objects

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Fourth
}
```

Finally, I have a variable with an `object` type something like this

```
object obj = new GenericEnumViewModel<TestEnum>(); // Notice at this point I don't know that the generic type is `TestEnum` it could be any Enum.
```

How can I check if the variable `obj` implements `GenericEnumViewModel<Enum>` ? Also how can I make a new variable called `castedObj` as `GenericEnumViewModel<Enum>`

I am trying to access `castedObj.Value` and `castedObj.Options`.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
var castedObj = obj as GenericEnumViewModel<Enum>;

if(castedObj != null)
{
      // do something with castedObj.Value and castedObj.Options.
}
```

Comment: would it be possible for your to pass on the enum type to the function you are calling as an generic argument e.g. `MyMethodWhichUsesEnum<TEnum>()`

Comment: @adeel41 I get the object from `System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata` so I won't no be able to pass the type

Comment: I would suggest to use `dynamic castedObj = obj` or use a `switch` statement on something like `obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I check if the variable obj implements GenericEnumViewModel ?

You can do this using reflection:

```
object obj = new GenericEnumViewModel<TestEnum>();

var objType = obj?.GetType();
var enumType =
    objType != null && objType.IsGenericType && objType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericEnumViewModel<>) ?
    objType.GetGenericArguments()[0] :
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Object is not a closed type of {typeof(GenericEnumViewModel<>).FullName}");
```

> Also how can I make a new variable called castedObj as GenericEnumViewModel

This is impossible for multiple reasons. The following line won't compile:

```
// this code is invalid!
GenericEnumViewModel<Enum> model = new GenericEnumViewModel<TestEnum>();
```

First of all, [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) is only allowed for interfaces, arrays and delegates in C#.

Furthermore, even if covariance were allowed for classes, [System.Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) is a reference type while enums are value types. Assigning an enum value to a System.Enum variable involves [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). This in itself would make the assignment above impossible.

However, you can workaround this by the help of a non-generic interface (or abstract base class) like this:

```
public interface IGenericEnumViewModel
{
    Enum Value { get; }
    GenericEnumViewModel<SelectListItem> Options { get; }
}

public class GenericEnumViewModel<TEnum> : IGenericEnumViewModel where TEnum : struct
{
    [Required]
    public TEnum? Value { get; set; }
    public GenericEnumViewModel<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    Enum IGenericEnumViewModel.Value => Value.HasValue ? Value.Value : (Enum)null;
}

// ...

if (obj is IGenericEnumViewModel castedObj)
{
    // do something with castedObj.Value and castedObj.Options.
    Enum value = castedObj.Value;
    // ...
}
```

**Bonus**

As of C# 7.3 [you can use Enum in generic type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints)!

```
public class GenericEnumViewModel<TEnum> : IGenericEnumViewModel where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why you said that `Assigning an enum value to a System.Enum variable involves boxing. This in itself makes the type cast above impossible.` Yo can write `int i = 1;` here `i` is value type variable. Then you can write `object o = i;` here `o` is reference type variable, and it now contains `i` value, and here boxing was performed. And casting was performed too, you implicitly cast `i` to `System.Object`.

Comment: And you can cast your enum variable to `System.Enum`. You can write `var castedEnum = (Enum) myEnum;` and it works. Just try it.

Comment: By `the type cast above` I meant the line `GenericEnumViewModel<Enum> model = new GenericEnumViewModel<TestEnum>();`. This is an assignment involving an implicit type cast. However, `the assigment above` would be clearer. I'll edit my post.

Comment: `var castedEnum = (Enum) myEnum;` will work obviously. However, boxing is performed here, too as Enum is a reference type. (Just like in the case of `object o = 1`.)

Comment: That why it's misleading: `Assigning an enum value to a System.Enum variable involves boxing. This in itself makes the type cast above impossible` sounds like `boxing makes type cast impossible`

Comment: I rephrased this part of my answer, I hope it's unambiguous now.

Answer (score -1):

You can add new interface and implement it explicitly. Then You can use pattern matching which was introduced in C# 7.0.

```
public interface IGenericEnumViewModel
{
    object Value { get; set; }
    GenericEnumViewModel<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
}

public class GenericEnumViewModel<TEnum> : IGenericEnumViewModel where TEnum : struct
{
    public TEnum? Value { get; set; }
    public GenericEnumViewModel<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

        object IGenericEnumViewModel.Value {
               get {return Value;}
               set {Value = (TEnum?)value;}
}
```

And then:

```
if(obj is IGenericEnumViewModel c)
{
      //c is IGenericEnumViewModel 
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't use Enum. When I use Enum I get the following error `The type 'Enum' must be a non-nullable type in order ti use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic method 'GenericEnumViewModel<TEnum>`

Comment: @MikeA why don't you check if it's GenericEnumViewModel<TestEnum> ? Or you want to check if it's GenericEnumViewModel<> ?